# Legitimacy of "construct from nothing"

Tags: phrasing

I was thinking today about the phrasing of 'construct something from nothing' (the context was constructing ideas), and I began to wonder if 'construct' was really a good word to use. Maybe I'm just getting into picky semantics, but I think of 'construct' as forming something out of some form of raw materials, or some type of resource. Anyway I was just wondering how legitimate this usage is and what alternatives might be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use

- **develop**, to give the idea of the being able to give life to something out of something else or nothing as you suggest. 
  To develop new ideas.

Comment: That does sound better to me, but as a follow-up question, can develop be used in a sense of something coming into existence, rather than 'develop'ing from something else? I know that develop can definitely be used to describe something growing and changing, but I'm not so sure about coming into existence from nothing (I don't think it's wrong, I really don't know). That said thanks for the response and sorry for my probably over-pickiness.

Comment: If the context is the one described in your last note to Erik Kowal, both my suggestion and his may fit your question. If you need a stronger word to use with the idea of 'out if nothing' you may use 'create'.

Comment: Well I think that answers my question, and I thank you both for humoring me (I wish I could accept two answers :\ )

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a problem here -- 'construct' can be used as easily with abstract entities as with physical ones.

For instance:

> I'm trying to construct a plausible plotline for my movie script.
>
> I've constructed a new theory to explain the economic processes that operate when essential resources are officially rationed.
>
> George has constructed a fantasy world in which everybody else is against him.

Comment: I guess I take issue not with the idea of abstraction, but with the fact that it comes from nothing (although maybe one follows from the other, idk). I don't necessarily have a problem with your examples, because I feel like they are built up from something, like other ideas and influences.

Comment: @KSab - Could you explain, in that case, what you mean by "from nothing"?

Comment: Well the context I used was something like: "Often these ideas are greatly influenced and skewed by later notions, and sometimes even just constructed out of nothing" in the sense that they had no real source.

Comment: The 'castles in the air' (construction) metaphor.